# Errno 24 Too many open files

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a virtual assistant program in Python on a Raspberry Pi 4 (using Thonny) and I've come across the above error.  My program is relatively simple but I'm unable to understand why the error keeps popping up after running the program for about 30 minutes.  My code is as follows:

```
def speak(text):

    text = ("<prosody rate='+0.20'><prosody volume='loud'>" + text + "</prosody>")
    subprocess.call(['swift', '-o', '/home/pi/response', text], shell=False)
    os.system('aplay /home/pi/response')
    
def greeting():

    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        speak("Initializing...  Starting program.  I am on line.  Good morning.")
    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("Initializing...  Starting program.  I am on line.  Good afternoon.")
    else:
        speak("Initializing...  Starting program.  I am on line.  Good evening.")
    
def listen_wakeWord():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.1)
        audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=7)        
    try:
        data = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
        print(f"You said: {data}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        #print(e)
        print("Input Not Recognized...")
      
greeting()

while True:

    try:
        listen_wakeWord()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```